# Ignoring duplicate entry at table records 130045, No further warning will be generated in this table in lookup of datastage

Tags: datastage

when my datastage run i am seeing a warning as Ignoring duplicate entry at table record 130045,No further warning will be generated in this table,

so what is the number 130045 means and how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

These warnings are usually shown if you get duplicates from a reference link in a lookup. The problem is that in that case it might hit the wrong "duplicate". Make sure the reference data is duplicate free regarding your lookup key.
Otherwise provide more information about your job structure and stages used.